# Как использовать переменные по запросу?

Tags: c#

Есть следующий код для примера:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo(20, gt);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

private static int gt
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("чтение переменной");
            return 100;
        }
    }

static void Foo(int z, int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("метод");
        if (z >= 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("переменная больше 10");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("переменная = " + x);
        }
    }
```

На данный момент он выводит следующее:

```
чтение переменной
метод
переменная больше 10
```

Оно и понятно, сначала читается переменная для передачи в качестве параметра, даже если она не используется в коде.

Как организовать метод чтобы использовать переменную "по запросу"? Т.е. чтобы она читалась только в момент ее использования, а не передачи параметром методу.

Comment: Не совсем понятны намерения. Т.к. свойство и вызов в одном классе, то и вызывать в в том месте где надо. `if (gt >= 10)`

Comment: @Vadim Prokopchuk: Ну, на самом деле не важно какие намерения, код для примера. Можно было выделить метод `Foo()` в отдельный класс, но это ничего не изменило бы. Просто хотелось оптимизировать один метод в классе, в котором от определенных условий обрабатываются или нет некие переменные заданные в параметрах, вызов которых довольно ресурсоемкий.

Comment: просто может имеет смысл найти другой подход? Вот, например, как ответил VladD про Lazy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Самый простой вариант — вы должны использовать *функцию*, которая получит нужное значение.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo(() => 20, () => gt);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static int gt
{
    get
    {
        Console.WriteLine("чтение переменной");
        return 100;
    }
}

static void Foo(Func<int> z, Func<int> x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("метод");
    if (z() >= 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("переменная больше 10");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("переменная = " + x());
    }
}
```

Пояснение: `Func<int>` означает функцию, которая возвращает значение типа `int`. `() => gt` — это лямбда-выражение, которое задаёт функцию, возвращающую при её вызове значение `gt`.

---

Ещё один вариант — воспользоваться классом `Lazy<T>`, который вычислит значение при первом опросе и лишь один раз, и запомнит его для следующих опросов.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // я пользуюсь непотокобезопасным вариантом, т. к. у нас нет многопоточности в коде
    Foo(new Lazy<int>(() => 20, false), new Lazy<int>(() => gt, false));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static int gt
{
    get
    {
        Console.WriteLine("чтение переменной");
        return 100;
    }
}

static void Foo(Lazy<int> z, Lazy<int> x)
{
    Console.WriteLine("метод");
    if (z.Value >= 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("переменная больше 10");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("переменная = " + x.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.

Comment: @ГеннадийП: Пожалуйста! Добавил ещё один, более продвинутый вариант.